# Port checking tool causes infinite packet received loop on TcpClient server

Tags: c#, tcp, mono, network-programming, tcpclient

I've written a relatively basic asynchronous server which boots up a task to accept clients and each client then boots up a task to accept incoming packets, the code for which is as follows:

```
        MessageListeningTask = new Task(async () => {
            while (true) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                try {
                    await tcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                } catch {
                    break;
                }
                string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer).Trim('\0', '\n', '\r', '\t', ' ');
                OnMessageReceived(data);
            }
        });
```

This seems to work pretty well for most things, and after routing it through a class that splits the tokens based on a token at the start, is quite an effective listener.

Except, given my naivety to the topic, I seem to have done something stupidly somewhere in my implementation, and checking with this tool: http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ seems to break this loop and cause it to trigger OnMessageReceived constantly with no data.

I'm not entirely sure what procedures to take to help diagnose this issue, and figure it's probably something to do with how the information stream operates, so I was hoping someone with experience in the topic could help me solve my issue but also explain what is causing it. If it's relevant, it's running under Mono on Ubuntu, but it usually runs perfectly so I can't see this being the issue.

I am happy to provide any additional information, or to check anything.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of mono are you using?

Comment: I'm on 4.0.2 (Apparently Stable 4.0.2.5/c99aa0c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of ReadAsync:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813(v=vs.110).aspx

"Return Value
Type: System.Threading.Tasks.Task
A task that represents the asynchronous read operation. The value of the TResult parameter contains the total number of bytes read into the buffer. The result value can be less than the number of bytes requested if the number of bytes currently available is less than the requested number, or it can be 0 (zero) if the end of the stream has been reached."

In the loop ReadAsync must be constantly returning 0 because it reached the end of stream.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to give an update; I'm a bit busy lately but I've seen your answer and as soon as I have time later, I'll verify this is the issue & accept.